# What prevent me from get this json data

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to get this array of images in this json bellow and display it in `GridView` but i don't know why i can't reach that >>>

```
    {
id: 241,
title: "title",
image: "1469370455.jpg",
description: " descriotion   ",
images: [
"1469370455.jpg",
"1469370458.jpg",
"1469370481.jpg",
"1469370484.jpg"
]}
```

and this is my full AyncTask.

```
     private class AysncImages extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
//            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
//            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
//            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
//            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // Building Parameters
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(String.valueOf(Config.BASE_URL));

            //jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url + 373); //or url + ID
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground Image: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {


                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    JSONArray arrayObj = jsonObj.getJSONArray("images");

                    Log.i(TAG, "array: "+ jsonObj);

                    GridItem item = new GridItem();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayObj.length(); i++) {
                        String images = arrayObj.getString(i);


                        Log.i(TAG, "parseResult: " + jsonObj);
                        item.setImage(IMAGE_LINK + images);//IMAGE_LINK +

                        Log.i(TAG, "parseResult: " + IMAGE_LINK + " " + images);
                        mGridData.add(item);

                    }
                    // Getting JSON Array node


                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
//            if (result == 1) {
                mGridAdapter.setGridData(mGridData);
            //} else {
              //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to fetch data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           // }

            //Hide progressbar
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }
```

In my log i can't reach `jsonObj` or `arrayObj` I just can reach `jsonStr` what I'm missing ?

My Log for `jsonStr`

[image]

Comment: How looks the logcat output?

Comment: @jorge i canr reach url `jsonStr` but i can't reach `jsonObj` `arrayObj`

Comment: Yes, but I mean if you can post your logcat output. Maybe jsonStr is null?

Comment: I Updated question

Comment: the 1st char is '[' is that mean the 1st one is already an array?

Comment: @CbL  what you refereeing to ?

Comment: first you should check your image url on browser

Comment: @sabir i cant get any result from object and array in log .!

Answer (score 0):

the json string you get is [{id:abc,...}]
but a JsonObject should start with {id:abc,...}
maybe you try to remove the '[' and ']' at the end of string in order to get the object

as start with '[' should be an array